# How to get a message unknown recipients email or name instead of 0 with facebook fql?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, message, facebook-fql

How to get a message unknown recipients email or name  instead of 0 with facebook fql?

I wrote some php code to export the messages in my facebook mailbox.
I am using FQL.

this is the flq multiquery I use in the [API tool explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to get a given message, with full message and recipients data.

```
{
"threads": "SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id IN (0,1,4)",
"messages": "SELECT thread_id, message_id, author_id, created_time, body FROM message where thread_id IN ( SELECT thread_id FROM #threads) and message_id='249...' ORDER BY created_time ASC",
"recipients_id": "SELECT thread_id,recipients FROM thread WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM #messages)",
"recipients": "SELECT uid, username, name, email, profile_url, pic FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT recipients FROM #recipients_id)"
}
```

Here is what I get:

```
{
    "name": "recipients_id", 
    "fql_result_set": [
      {
        "thread_id": "26854010378569", 
        "recipients": [
          4735804651, 
          0, 
          0
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

As I prior sent this test message from a classic email client to my facebook address, I know who is the sender of this message.
4735804651 is my facebook ID, the last two values (zero) in the recipient field refer to the sender and another facebook user which is not my friend.
In the original email I sent, I put my @facebook.com email and another @m.facebook.com user email
Everybody received the message.
When I read it from the FB interface and fly over the sender name, I can see the sender email address.
How can I get it through facebook api or FQL?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You first must get the *folder_id* where is the message: //0 inbox, 1 otubox, 4 updates//

```
SELECT folder_id, name, unread_count, viewer_id FROM mailbox_folder WHERE viewer_id=me()
```

When get the *folder_id* you can get the *thread_id* :

```
SELECT thread_id  FROM thread WHERE folder_id = x AND viewer_id=me()
```

And with this *thread_id* you get all the messages from it:

```
SELECT message_id, author_id, body, created_time, viewer_id FROM message WHERE thread_id = xxxxxxx
```

and all summarized:

```
SELECT message_id, thread_id, author_id, body, created_time, viewer_id FROM message WHERE thread_id   in (SELECT thread_id  FROM thread WHERE folder_id in(SELECT folder_id  FROM mailbox_folder WHERE viewer_id=me()) AND viewer_id=me())
```

***For all this you need an app token***

you can try it here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer